# Send Property from class to VM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have two classes(classVM and class1). In my class1 I have gotten a parameter from the View. Everything in that sense works.

However I need to transfer that parameter to classVM without creating an instance of the classVM in class1.

How should I go about doing this?

---

Edit:

The parameter(it is a property) gets populated from a behavior in the view.
Once that property gets populated, another property in the VM needs to get populated with parameter/property.

---

Edit:

**xaml**

```
<dataContext:ItemTemplateSelectorClass>
    <dataContext:ItemTemplateSelectorClass.StringTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Description}" Height="25" Width="75"/>
                <TextBox Text="{Binding Value}" Height="23" Width="100">
                    <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                        <dataContext:TextBoxBehavior Parameter="{Binding Description}"/>
                    </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                </TextBox>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </dataContext:ItemTemplateSelectorClass.StringTemplate>
```

the parameter in TextBoxBehavior is a attached property I created to fill. The description and value bindings are in another class. I was to separate the different types of properties, methods and commands into different classes for error handling (I know not the best way to do it, but this is what I had to do.) The binding to the behavior works fine.

**xaml datacontext**

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <dataContext:FieldsModel x:Name="dataContext" />
</Window.DataContext>
```

**VM Property**

```
private object selectedField;
    public object SelectedField {
        get {
            return selectedField;
        }
        set {
            if (selectedField != value) {
                selectedField = value;
                SetPropertyChanged("SelectedField");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You can use two-way multi data binding and also bind the control from within the View to the ViewModel as well

Comment: You're doing something wrong.  Step back, learn more, then come back to this.

Answer (score 0):

You should store the value not in the view but in the model; or if the 'parameter' (possibly you mean property) is from some property inside a control in the View, copy it to the view model.

Comment: The property that gets populated first is in class1. The property that then needs to be populated is in classVM. Both classes have properties within them that can be populated. I cant move these properties around, they have to stay in the respective classes.

Comment: I think I lack some information to give a dedicated answer in that case. Since you want to store a property in the VM (which should be already made I assume), why not using that reference?

Comment: The property is already made. Just needs to be set. When you say reference it, what exactly do you mean?

Comment: You have already class1.X (let's call the property X). Since VM is not yet created. However, at one time VM will be created, and you can reference it at that time (something like VM.X = ViewInstance.Class1instancer.X).